# What does SP mean in `CSI Ps SP A` xterm escape command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, escape-characters, xterm

I am learning ansi escape codes with xterm. And according to [this](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) there is the following escape code:

> CSI Ps SP A - Shift right Ps columns(s) (default = 1) (SR), ECMA-48.

Could anyone explain what is `SP`? Is it `SPACE`? I am asking as I tried it with space with the following command:

```
printf "\033[20 A"
```

But it didn't show any changes in ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is space. If you look at [ECMA-48 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-48_5th_edition_june_1991.pdf), page 68, point 8.3.35, you have:

> SR: CSI Pn 02/00 04/01

It use the old ASCII (and other encoding) notation, but 02/00 is 0x20 so equivalent of SP, if you are using ASCII encoding, and 04/01 is 0x41 (A if you are using ASCII encoding).

I think that function works only on some modes, but I'm not sure, and nothing in standard and in xterm site (that you linked) gives us hints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And could you explain what `02/00` and `04/01` is? I've never seen such encoding?

Comment: It is the old notation: number of column (from 0, in decimal numbers) and number of row (also from zero and in decimal numbers) of the character table. But you can just multiply the first number with 16 and add the second number, and you have the code. `07/15` is 127 (or 0x7F: 0xF is 15), so DELETE character.

Comment: In other words, it’s hex, but not using the alphanumeric hex digits we use today, but rather writing each base-16 position as a two-digit decimal number.  `02/00` is 0x20, `04/01` is 0x41, `07/15` is 0x7F, etc.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': yes, but note the "two decimal number" is *recent* (, e.g. you see it in version 1991 of ECMA/ISO), older ECMA (and ASCII) just had 7/15, 4/1 (and they still refer sometime about columns and rows, e.g. topic of this question CSI final character must be in column 4 to column 7). Lucky they didn't pass to the octal numeration, and luckily Unicode used hexadecimal (since beginning).

Answer (score 2):

The name is explained in the same source, i.e., [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Single-character-functions:SP.BE8)

It works in any mode of xterm:

- added in [2011](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_277):

> - add ISO and DEC controls useful for left/right scrolling.

- not a feature of [VT100/VT220/etc](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/834b501a1416d7f14b1c38705083f413aea92eee/util.c#L773):

```
    /*
     * This is from ISO 6429, not found in any of DEC's terminals.
     */
```

- probably not implemented (like [70-80%](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions) of xterm) in a given xterm-imitator.  "ubuntu terminal" is on the low side of that range.

Comment: I see you are an expert in terminals and escape codes. Could you say, if there is a regex pattern that can detect any escape sequence code, for example ESC[...., ESC].... ESCN...? I need this regex pattern for ansi escape code parser. Currently I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693789/5057736 but it seems not to support all types.

Comment: For "most" (I didn't do C1 controls in that), see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441995/unix-script-command-includes-gibberish-in-export/39442028#39442028).  Handling all controls in a POSIX shell/sed script would be harder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.